# Define all functions on $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a very basic question. I have a function on one angularjs controller that does stuff. I don't need to use it directly from the view. No other controller needs this function, eliminating the need to define it on a service. Seems to me this does not need to be defined on $scope. It can just be,

```
function doStuff() {
    // stuff done
}
```

Does convention dictate that I define all such simple functions on $scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no.  It's simply a reusable function that you would define within the scope of the controller.  If it's only used within, there's no need to muddy up your `$scope` with functions not being used with your user interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, only methods which serve some UI interaction purpose.